# Testing multiple servers with spring boot test

Tags: java, spring, maven, testing, spring-boot-test

I have a multi-module maven project with a spring service in each module.
The problem I have is that I want to create a test with multiple servers.

So currently I have a couple of tests that are actually starting a server and doing some requests to it using the annotation `@SpringBootTest`. And preferably I would like to test multiple servers with the same approach as it gives me the opportunity to mock for example the database connections. And I can of course mock parts of the HTTP calls if needed so that the servers can "communicate".

So I guess the question is: 
Is it possible to test multiple servers in this way?

Comment: The question which comes into my mind: What kind of tests are you doing if you start servers etc. ? Furthermore in such cases I would suggest to take a look at https://www.testcontainers.org/

Comment: The tests that I have right now are testing the flow between components inside one server. But there is nothing that tests that the servers are communicating properly with eachother(there are no clear requirements so we don't know what is working and what isn't). The issue with testcontainers.org is that I don't seem to be able to mock the contents of the database. We are using oracle with a bunch of tables, views and procedures making it quite difficult to setup in a test docker environment

Comment: Than I don't understand the part:  `The problem I have is that I want to create a test with multiple servers.`...

Comment: You're talking about a full integration test, and the way that's usually done is to have some sort of management software (e.g., Spinnaker) that deploys the different components and then runs the tests externally, making remote calls like a normal client would.

Comment: hmm, ok, to clarify I have a database `A` and two servers `B` and `C`. Both `B` and `C` communicates with `A`, but `A` is to complex to start and thus I need to mock it. What I want to test is that `B` can send propper requests to `C`.